# How can I view downloaded files in the iPhone's Files and Photos apps using cordova-plugin-advanced-http?

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, monaca, cordova-plugin-advanced-http

Even if I download the image URL file with the following code, it cannot be viewed in the iPhone's Files and Photos apps. How do I do that?

```
await cordova.plugin.http.downloadFile(
            imageUrl,
            {},
            {},
            cordova.file.documentsDirectory + fileName,
            // success callback
            function(entry, response) {
              console.info(entry.name + ' saved successfully.');
            },
            // error callback
            function(response) {
              console.log(response.error);
            }
        );
```

At least I can see it in the Files app.

Comment: You are using the wrong plugin and the wrong directory

Comment: Which plugin should I use and in which folder should I save it

Comment: cordova-plugin-file then read https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file#where-to-store-files